# Magento 2 single site to magento 2 multisite database migration

Tags: magento, magento2, data-migration, sql-scripts

We are having 3 different magento 2.0 stores CE functionally migrated to magento 2.4 multisite environment with test data.

We want to migrate actual data from all 3 sites to new portal.

1. Is there any tool/script available?
2. Which tables do we need to migrate?
3. How we can avoid duplicate customer id/order id problem?

Comment: Is this a programming related question? BTW, asking for tools or scripts is off-topic here.

Comment: Yes This question is raised to identify the best way to migrate data keeping customer data in sync.

Comment: No, sorry, is this specifically a programming-related question or are you asking for any solution?

Comment: It is related to magento programming if you can help.

Comment: Please post the code you're having trouble with, along with what the issue is, and how you need it to work.